# How to Configure OSMC to output composite video on Raspberry Pi 2?

Tags: pi-2, kodi, composite-video, osmc

I have an http://osmc.tv (a Kodi distribution) setup on my Raspberry Pi 2. It works fine when plugging in the HDMI cable for video output. However, the composite video through the combined a/v jack does not work.

It seems to be that I need to configure the OS to use the Composite video output instead of HDMI.

Could someone direct me to either the steps necessary or a resource outlining how to configure OSMC (Kodi) to out put to Composite video on Raspberry Pi 2?

Comment: I've tried adding the "sdtv_mode=0" to the config.txt file on the SD card, but that didn't work. https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/config-txt.md

Comment: make sure that the HDMI cable is not connected on boot and try this hdmi_ignore_hotplug=1
sdtv_mode=0 
and commented out hdmi_safe=1. in your config.txt file (you may not have this line in your file). If the above does not work pleease post the contents of your config.txt

Comment: I assume osmc includes the normal Pi tools. `tvservice -c "PAL 4:3"` should put into PAL (similar for NTSC)